# Как повторно выполнить animate?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, animate

```
textView5.clearAnimation();
textView5.animate().cancel;
textView5.setTop(50);
textView5.animate().translationY(300).start();
```

Написал вот так на нажатие button-а.
При первом нажатий все отлично выполнилась - фигура `textView5` опустилась на 300 пикселей вниз. 
При втором повторном нажатий кнопки текстовое поле должна была переместится в 50-ый пиксель и снова должна была падать до 300-го пикселя.
Но, так не случилось - `textView5` замерла в 300-ом пикселе и сколько раз не нажимай кнопку все равно не двигается.
В чем же моя ошибка?

Comment: Наличие либо отстутствие упоминания Android Studio в вопросе никак не влияет на решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать вот так. И заодчно почитать про [анимации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views).

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView5,"translationY",50,300).start();
```